# Is it "glowed" or "glown" when conjugating "glow"?

Tags: verbs, past-tense, spelling, irregular-forms

I want to say *he's glown with brilliance* but the spell checker barks at me for misspelling, like if it prefers *glowed*.

[This resource](https://preply.com/en/question/past-tense-of-glow) commands the **latter**, while [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/4a2kr2/the_past_tense_of_glow_should_be_glew_not_glowed/) the exact **opposite**. I've also found [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94995/imperfective-and-perfective-aspects-of-verb-glow) giving me little understanding as they seem not to suggest **any**. Checking [Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glow) confused me even more as they list **both**.

So, which is it and how can I confirm that?

Comment: It looks as though you are trying to make _glow_ into a transitive verb, which it is not. You have to say _he glowed_. (Your second link is not to be taken seriously; it's just people playing with words.)

Comment: yes—the verb tense here seems a bit off. Usually you talk about "he was glowing with ..." or "he glowed with..."

Comment: I've voted to close because this could be answered by a dictionary. "Glown" just isn't found in it at all, and it would tell you the correct from of "to glow".

Comment: Please do not consider Reddit a reliable source for English language learning. That thread was a joke, anyway. Check your favorite dictionary or dictionaries! I'm also not sure why Wikipedia confused you since it clearly marks "glown" as "nonstandard."

Comment: I agree. The Reddit is intended as a joke.

Comment: The link marked as "Wikipedia" is actually to "Wiktionary". It shows "glown", noun and verb, not as a form of "glow", but as a mutation of "clown" as noun and verb.

Comment: @KateBunting I'm not sure what makes you think that I'm trying to use *glow* as transitive verb. In the expression *he has glown*, adding with what, how or when, doesn't make it transitive, does it?

Comment: @TypeIA I understand now the significance of *nonstandard* there. I assumed it was congruent with *irregular* or something like that.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica That joke played a joke on me. I didn't realize it wasn't seriously meant. How naive it may sound, when I google stuff, I usually trust what I see. Especially in this case, as it sounded feasible to me that *glown* might be correct.

Comment: You wrote _He's glown_, which I interpreted as _He is glown_. In discussions such as this you need to spell it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest first looking this up [in any dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=glown). You'll most often get no results——that is, 0 results found in your search. As shown [here](https://www.dictionary.com/misspelling?term=glown&s=t).

You can also use [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/conj/EnVerbs.aspx?v=glow) to show you conjugated forms.

According to [usage examples in the OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/79220), *glowed* is the past participle of *glow*. *Glown* is indicated as a form, but a rare form, and not cited in any of the examples.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the statement *you'll often get no results*. What's confusing to me is the fact that absence of proof is not a proof of absence. Getting no results shows that I may be poor at searching, rather than I can conclude there's no such thing. Or am I mistaken, please?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: When you search for past participles that _don't exist_, you'll get 0 results. When you search for past participles (or other verb forms) that do exist, you will be directed to the appropriate headword: _glow_, in this case.

I also recommend double-checking forms in WordReference's English verb conjugator, when you have doubts. I updated the answer to include this info.